# cuando subo mi proyecto de php a cpanel me sale errores?

Tags: php, cpanel

cuando subo un proyecto de php al cpanel no me reconoces las setencias de php, por ejemplo en el codigo que les voy pasar hago una consulta a la base de datos para llenar un combo box pero me sale un error en el error log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in
```

y todo el codigo que esta despues no se ve como los demas input o botones solo carga antes del error,cuando hago una prueba a mi conexion si da correcto

soy nuevo espero que me puedan ayudar, creo q debo agregar algo mas.. gracias

el codigo es este :

```
<?php  
  include '../conexionbd.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>ASPATPERU-SISBIO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/component.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/formregistro.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo_contenedor3.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

                  <style type="text/css">
                     .ca-menu .datospersonales{
                  background: #D5FFBB;

                     }



                  </style>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcularedad(){

        var fecha_hoy = new Date();
        var ano_hoy = fecha_hoy.getYear();
        var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth() +1;
        var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();
        var fechanac = document.getElementById('user_date').value
        var valores = fechanac.split('-');


        var ano=valores[0];
        var mes=valores[1];
        var dia=valores[2];




        var edad = (ano_hoy + 1900) - ano;


        if ( ahora_mes < mes )
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia))
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if (edad > 1900)
        {
            edad -= 1900;
        }


        document.getElementById('edad').innerHTML="Edad : " +edad + " años";




  }



</script>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>


     <img class="bannerimg" src="../img/portadainicio.jpg"/>


        <div class="container" >    
            <div class="main clearfix">
                <nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
                    <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="../inicio.php">
                                <span id=primero class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Principal</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="paciente_incio.php">
                                <span id="segundo" class="icon"> 
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-stethoscope"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Pacientes</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="tercero" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-paste"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Reporte</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="cuarto" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-group"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Ayuda</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="quinto" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-team"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>The team</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="sexto" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Contact</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
<div id="contenedor3">
     <div class="content">
                <ul class="ca-menu">
                    <li class="datospersonales"> 
                        <a href="crear_paciente.php">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Datos Personales</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="esquema_tratamiento">
                        <a href="crear_esquema.php">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Esquema de Tratamieto</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de datos del tratamiento</h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Control Clinico</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de medicamentos</h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                  <!--
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Unconditional Support</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub">24/7 for you needs</h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    -->
                </ul>
        </div><!-- content -->
<?php  

//Consulta

$consulta_cingreso = 'SELECT * FROM condicion_ingreso';
$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cingreso);

$consulta_titratamiento = 'SELECT * FROM  tipo_tratamiento';
$resultado_titratamiento = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_titratamiento);

?>

<form action="guardarpaciente.php" method="post" class="form_registro" >
<div class="formularioregistro">

      <legend>DATOS PERSONALES        
      DATOS CLINICOS</legend>       
            <div id="tipo_Documento" >
                <select>
                   <option>Tipo de documento</option>
                    <option value="dni">DNI</option>
                    <option value="pn">PN</option>
                    <option value="ce">CE</option>
                    <option value="sd">SD</option>              
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="txtDni">
                <input type="text" name="dni"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"  maxlength="8"  required placeholder="Numero de documento"    autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%;">
            </div>

          <div id="tipo_tratamiento" >
                <select name="tipo_tratamiento">

                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_titratamiento->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                   <option  value="<?php echo $row['cod_tip_tratamiento'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_tipo_tratamiento']; ?></option>    

                                             <?php
    }    
    ?> 

                </select>
            </div>


            <div id="contenedor4">    
            <div id="txtnombre">  
                <input type="text" name="nombre"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Nombre"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;" >          
            </div>
            <div id="txtapellidop">
                <input type="text" name="apellidop"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Apellido Paterno"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
            <div id="txtapellidom">
                <input type="text" name="apellidom"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Apellido Materno"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>


            <div id="condicioningreso">
                <select id="comobocingreso" name="condicion_ingreso" >

                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_ingreso->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['cod_cingreso'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_condicion_ingreso']; ?></option>

                                 <?php
    }    
    ?>      
                </select>
            </div>


            </div>
            <div id="contenedor7">
            <div id="fchanacimiento">

             <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label><input name="user_date" id="user_date" type="date" name="fechanac"   autocomplete="off"   onchange="calcularedad()" style="height: 20%;width: 128%;">

            </div>
            <div id="edad">
                <label id="edad"></label>    
            </div>

            <div id="txtnumerocaso">
                <input type="text" name="numero_de_caso"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Numero de caso"   autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%;" >
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id=contenedor12>
            <div id="sexo">
                 <select>
                   <option>Sexo</option>
                    <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                    <option value="F">Femenino</option>                             
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="historiacli">
                <input type="text" name="historia"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Numero de historia clinica"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; margin-top:0px; margin-left: -70px;" >
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenedor5">
            <div id="talla">
                <input type="text" name="talla"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="Talla"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; width: 128%;"> 
            </div>
            <div id="peso">
                <input type="text" name="peso"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" autocomplete="off" required  placeholder="Peso" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="contenedor6">
            <div id="telefono">
                <input type="number" name="telefono"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required placeholder="telefono"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
             <div id="celular">
                <input type="number" name="celular" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required  placeholder="celular"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div id="contenedor8">
               <select id="pais">
                   <option>Pais</option>
                    <option>Peru</option>
                   <option>Uruguay</option>

               </select>

               <select id="departamento">
                   <option>Departamento</option>
                    <option>Peru</option>
                   <option>Uruguay</option>

               </select>
           </div>

              <select id="provincia">
                   <option>Provincia</option>
                    <option>Peru</option>
                   <option>Uruguay</option>

               </select>

               <select id="distrito">
                   <option>Distrito</option>
                    <option>Peru</option>
                   <option>Uruguay</option>

               </select>
           <div id="direccion">
               <input type="text" name="direccion"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"  required placeholder="Direcion"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; width: 38%;">
           </div>

            <input id="btnguardar" type="submit" value="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn-enviar">


</div>

</form>

</div>

        <script>
            //  The function to change the class
            var changeClass = function (r,className1,className2) {
                var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className1 + "(?:\\s+|$)");
                if( regex.test(r.className) ) {
                    r.className = r.className.replace(regex,' '+className2+' ');
                }
                else{
                    r.className = r.className.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className2 + "(?:\\s+|$)"),' '+className1+' ');
                }
                return r.className;
            };  

            //  Creating our button in JS for smaller screens
            var menuElements = document.getElementById('menu');
            menuElements.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<button type="button" id="menutoggle" class="navtoogle" aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-menu"> </i> Menu</button>');

            //  Toggle the class on click to show / hide the menu
            document.getElementById('menutoggle').onclick = function() {
                changeClass(this, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
            }

            // http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/comment-page-2/#comment-438918
            document.onclick = function(e) {
                var mobileButton = document.getElementById('menutoggle'),
                    buttonStyle =  mobileButton.currentStyle ? mobileButton.currentStyle.display : getComputedStyle(mobileButton, null).display;

                if(buttonStyle === 'block' && e.target !== mobileButton && new RegExp(' ' + 'active' + ' ').test(' ' + mobileButton.className + ' ')) {
                    changeClass(mobileButton, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

este es el fragmento de codigo donde me dice cpnel que es error

```
<div id="tipo_tratamiento" >
                <select name="tipo_tratamiento">

                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_titratamiento->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                   <option  value="<?php echo $row['cod_tip_tratamiento'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_tipo_tratamiento']; ?></option>    

                                             <?php
    }    
    ?> 

                </select>
            </div>
```

pdt :  en lo local host si funciona correctamente

Comment: haz un php_info() en el servidor y en tu maquina local y dinos la version de php que utiliza cada una

Comment: gracias por la rspuesta la version de php en el servidor es 5.4.45 y en mi maquina es 5.6.3

Comment: bueno tienes dos opciones uno actualizar el servidor dos actualizar tu entorno de desarrollo en ambos casos te podremos ayudar con cada uno de los errores

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que los datos de conexión a la `DB` son correctos y que las tablas existen?

Comment: Haz un var_dump(mysql_error());

Comment: Para este caso creo que es necesario que muestres la configuración de la conexión de tu base de datos (obviando los datos de acceso) con ello se podría ver cuál error tienes.